# Laravel ajax give error 500

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to add data to database by ajax and i get error 500 in network.

## codes

`ajax`

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready( function() {
    $("#modalsave1").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "{{ url('admin/addnewsuboptionprodcreat') }}",
      data: {
        '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
        'subopttitle': $('input[name=subopttitle]').val(),
        'opt_id': $('#opt_id').val(),
        'subopt_price': $('#subopt_price').val(),
        'subopt_sku': $('#subopt_sku').val(),
        'optstat_id': $('#optstat_id').val(),
      },
      success: function (data) {
          $('#msg').append('<span class="text-success">Option added successfully!</span>');
          console.log(data);
      },
      error: function (data) {
          console.log('Error:', data);
      }
    });
  });
  });
</script>
```

`blade (form)`

```
{{Form::open()}}
  //form inputs
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" id="modalsave1" class="modalsave1 btn btn-primary">Save</button>
  </div>
{{Form::close()}}
```

`controller`

```
public function addnewsuboptionprodcreat(Request $reqs)
{
      $add = Suboption::create([
          'title' => $reqs->subopttitle,
          'option_id' => $reqs->opt_id,
          'price' => $reqs->subopt_price,
          'sku' => $reqs->subopt_sku,
          'status_id' => $reqs->optstat_id,
      ]);
}
```

## error

```
"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `suboptions` (`title`, `option_id`, `price`, `sku`, `status_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (ssssssss, 1, 3232323, sfdsfsf, 1, 2018-07-17 08:03:41, 2018-07-17 08:03:41))"
```

> PS: while here in error mentioned `1062 Duplicate entry` i can assure
>   you that there is no same info in my table to be `duplicated`.

any idea?

## Update

`suboptions table schema`

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('suboptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title')->unique();
            $table->string('price');
            $table->string('sku')->nullable();
            $table->integer('option_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('status_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table('suboptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('option_id')->references('id')->on('options');
            $table->foreign('status_id')->references('id')->on('statuses');
        });
    }
```

Comment: *Integrity constraint violation* no, thats unrelated to `csrf`, please remove the tag.

Comment: Show your table definition, most likely missing an autoincrement column.

Comment: @Devon updated.

Comment: @mafortis looks right to me but the error seems to suggest it's trying to insert a 0 in your primary key column, which would be id.  Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE suboptions;` in a mysql client to confirm the table structure matches your migration.

Comment: where should i run that?

Comment: In any mysql client.  Or you could run it in tinker using DB::select();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## solved

Somehow in local it doesn't work and returns error 500 but on live host it works just fine!

PS: **to moderates** please close this question.

Thanks/.